# Vue.js PWA Plugin not loading service-worker.js when deployed to subfolder (Github Pages)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, vue-cli

I used the Vue CLI to create a new Vue project, and selected PWA support when using 'vue create'.

I also used the vue-gh-pages plugin to deploy the app to a github pages URL.

The problem is that it's attempting to load 
http://myusername.github.io/service-worker.js
..instead of:
http://myusername.github.io/app-name/service-worker.js

Inside of **/src/registerServiceWorker.js** I can noticed:

```
register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
```

But when I attempt to set the BASE_URL in vue.config.js with:

```
module.exports = {
   baseUrl: '/app-name/'
}
```

..it breaks the links from all of the other scripts.

The app works when I run it locally, along with the PWA support.  Anyone know how to get this to work with sub folders / github pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgetting to build your project before you deploy it.  If you are running a Vue CLI that uses a build process, you should be running `npm run build` which will generate a `dist` folder that has all your resources as a static bundle.

You should commit **that** to your `gh-pages` branch and serve that instead.

I'm saying this because `process.env.BASE_URL` is something that the `node.js` side of things understands.  GitHub pages won't be populating that for you at runtime since it only serves content statically.

Comment: The vue-gh-pages plugin I'm using allows you to run an npm script that builds the project (npm run build) and deploys it to GH.

Comment: @GarySimon Ah, missed that.  You may need to open an issue on that repo then because something is not getting transformed correctly.

Comment: @GarySimon no matter what, it won't be serving out of `src`, it will be serving from `dist`.  You can see that since the plugin still runs `build` internally and then copies dist at [this line](https://github.com/KieferSivitz/vue-gh-pages/blob/master/index.js#L59).